# Error CS1503 "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ElementReference' to 'object?[]?'"

Tags: javascript, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

At my Blazor app I need the div-element size and this for I use

```html
<div class="modal-body" id="pdfView"> ... </div>
```

and

```
private ElementReference pdfView;
private async void VariablesService_OnWindowDimensionChange()
{
    var dimensions = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getDimensions", pdfView);
}
```

and at the index.html

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDimensions(element) {
            return JSON.stringify(document.getElementById(element).getBoundingClientRect());
        }
</script>
```

I get the error message:

> "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ElementReference' to 'object?[]?'"

**What courses this error?**

[image]

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem but you have to use the `@ref` attribute `<div class="modal-body" @ref="pdfView"> ... </div>`

Comment: Nope Dimitris Maragkos, it does not make any difference. I tried.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. If you can share a minimal reproducible example e.g. on github I'll gladly take a look.

Comment: Why do you use `document.getElementById(element) ?` It should be `element.getBoundingClientRect()` If you want to use document.getElementById(), send the element's id instead

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get element dimensions, I hope it helps.
Relevant parts from my service:

```cs
private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

// service constructor
public JSInteropCoreService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
{
    this.moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
          identifier: "import", args: "./_content/BJSInteroptCore/bCore.js").AsTask());
}

public async ValueTask<ElementBoundingRectangle> GetElementBoundingRectangleAsync(ElementReference elementReference)
{
    IJSObjectReference module = await GetModuleAsync();
    return await module.InvokeAsync<ElementBoundingRectangle>(identifier: "getBoundingRectangle", elementReference);
}

private async Task<IJSObjectReference> GetModuleAsync()
    => await this.moduleTask.Value;
```

```
public class ElementBoundingRectangle
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Right { get; set; }
    public double Bottom { get; set; }
    public double Left { get; set; }
}
```

JavaScript :

```js
export function getBoundingRectangle(element, parm) {
    return element.getBoundingClientRect();
}
```

Comment: So far I don't get it running. What is GetModuleAsync()? And how you hand over the elementReference to GetElementBoundingRectangleAsync() respectively how you get the html element into this function? (I guess here is my problem) At your js the second argument is never used, so why it is in?

Comment: No its not used. It is one of the standard parameters for the calling jsinteropt functions. Ignore it. As the method signature indicates `ElementReference` which is from `@ref` on the element. Note: @ref will only contain a value until after it is rendered.  So you have to call the function in the `OnAfterRenderAsync` of your component/page

Comment: A demo to show it works : https://brianparker.azurewebsites.net/ click on the eyeballs in the corner...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it appeared that I've forgotten to inject JSRuntime into my component.

Add `@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime` at the beginning of razor / C# file.
Use `@ref` decorator in the template to reference to the proper html element.

[Blazor university link](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/passing-html-element-references/)